# Convert multiindex pandas dataframe to polars dataframe

Tags: python-polars

I wanted to convert the pandas dataframe into a poalrs dataframe but the pandas dataframe came with a multiindex. So I wanted to know if there's a way we can flatten the multiinex and would achieve something look like the expected output:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
    ('Date', ''): {
        0: Timestamp('2022-04-07 00:00:00'),
        1: Timestamp('2022-04-08 00:00:00'),
        2: Timestamp('2022-04-11 00:00:00'),
        3: Timestamp('2022-04-12 00:00:00'),
        4: Timestamp('2022-04-13 00:00:00')
    },
    ('Adj Close', 'AAPL'): {
        0: 171.10350036621094,
        1: 169.0658416748047,
        2: 164.75196838378906,
        3: 166.65049743652344,
        4: 169.3739776611328
    },
    ('Adj Close', 'SPY'): {
        0: 441.29339599609375,
        1: 440.1134033203125,
        2: 432.5908508300781,
        3: 430.9880065917969,
        4: 435.92437744140625
    },
    ('Close', 'AAPL'): {0: 172.13999938964844, 1: 170.08999633789062, 2: 165.75, 3: 167.66000366210938, 4: 170.39999389648438},
    ('Close', 'SPY'): {0: 448.7699890136719, 1: 447.57000732421875, 2: 439.9200134277344, 3: 438.2900085449219, 4: 443.30999755859375},
    ('High', 'AAPL'): {0: 173.36000061035156, 1: 171.77999877929688, 2: 169.02999877929688, 3: 169.8699951171875, 4: 171.0399932861328},
    ('High', 'SPY'): {0: 450.69000244140625, 1: 450.6300048828125, 2: 445.0, 3: 445.75, 4: 444.1099853515625},
    ('Low', 'AAPL'): {0: 169.85000610351562, 1: 169.1999969482422, 2: 165.5, 3: 166.63999938964844, 4: 166.77000427246094},
    ('Low', 'SPY'): {0: 443.5299987792969, 1: 445.94000244140625, 2: 439.3900146484375, 3: 436.6499938964844, 4: 437.8399963378906},
    ('Open', 'AAPL'): {0: 171.16000366210938, 1: 171.77999877929688, 2: 168.7100067138672, 3: 168.02000427246094, 4: 167.38999938964844},
    ('Open', 'SPY'): {0: 445.5899963378906, 1: 447.9700012207031, 2: 444.1099853515625, 3: 443.0799865722656, 4: 438.0299987792969},
    ('Volume', 'AAPL'): {0: 77594700, 1: 76575500, 2: 72246700, 3: 79265200, 4: 70618900},
    ('Volume', 'SPY'): {0: 78097200, 1: 79272700, 2: 89770500, 3: 84363600, 4: 74070400}
}
)
```

Expected output:

```
           Date  Attribute Ticker         Value
0    2022-04-07  Adj Close   AAPL  1.711035e+02
1    2022-04-08  Adj Close   AAPL  1.690658e+02
2    2022-04-11  Adj Close   AAPL  1.647520e+02
3    2022-04-12  Adj Close   AAPL  1.666505e+02
4    2022-04-13  Adj Close   AAPL  1.693740e+02
...         ...        ...    ...           ...
3007 2023-03-31     Volume    SPY  1.119746e+08
3008 2023-04-03     Volume    SPY  6.739110e+07
3009 2023-04-04     Volume    SPY  6.660150e+07
3010 2023-04-05     Volume    SPY  6.520020e+07
3011 2023-04-06     Volume    SPY  6.357570e+07
```

Comment: What is really the question ? Do you want to know how your data must be presented to Panda ? or do you want a script which convert your data presented by column into a list of lines ?

Comment: I wanted to convert the pandas dataframe into a poalrs dataframe but the pandas dataframe came with a multiindex. So I wanted to know if there's a way we can flatten the multiinex and would achieve something look like the expected output.

Comment: You can `df.melt("Date")` - and rename the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use melt (as mentioned by @jqurious), then rename the other columns

```py
pl.from_pandas(df.melt('Date')) \
.rename({'variable_0': 'Attribute', 'variable_1': 'Symbol'})

# Output
┌─────────────────────┬───────────┬────────┬────────────┐
│ Date                ┆ Attribute ┆ Symbol ┆ value      │
│ ---                 ┆ ---       ┆ ---    ┆ ---        │
│ datetime[ns]        ┆ str       ┆ str    ┆ f64        │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════════╪════════╪════════════╡
│ 2022-04-07 00:00:00 ┆ Adj Close ┆ AAPL   ┆ 171.1035   │
│ 2022-04-08 00:00:00 ┆ Adj Close ┆ AAPL   ┆ 169.065842 │
│ 2022-04-11 00:00:00 ┆ Adj Close ┆ AAPL   ┆ 164.751968 │
│ 2022-04-12 00:00:00 ┆ Adj Close ┆ AAPL   ┆ 166.650497 │
│ …                   ┆ …         ┆ …      ┆ …          │
│ 2022-04-08 00:00:00 ┆ Volume    ┆ SPY    ┆ 7.92727e7  │
│ 2022-04-11 00:00:00 ┆ Volume    ┆ SPY    ┆ 8.97705e7  │
│ 2022-04-12 00:00:00 ┆ Volume    ┆ SPY    ┆ 8.43636e7  │
│ 2022-04-13 00:00:00 ┆ Volume    ┆ SPY    ┆ 7.40704e7  │
└─────────────────────┴───────────┴────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: Apologies - I should have been clearer, I meant: `pl.from_pandas(df.melt("Date"))`

Comment: fair point. doing the melt in Pandas makes for an easier code, I update the answer